# implementation class vector of generic data c++

Tags: c++

guys I wanted to know how you could implement a generic data vector class with certain attributes and methods that I will write to you. I wanted to know how methods should be implemented. How the class should be instantiated with the method recall in main. And also a suggestion to divide

I would also like to know from you how I could divide the whole implementation into three parts (main.cpp, vector.cpp, vector.hpp) I know that such an implementation is not the best but the professor wants this so there is no choice.

this should be the **vector.hpp**

```
namespace lasd{

  template <typename Data>
  class Vector{

    private:
      int dimensione;
      Data* array;
      int corrente;

    public:
      Vector();
      void push(int data);
      void push(int data,int index);
      int get(int index);
      void pop();
      int size();
      void getDimensione();
      int getCapacity();
      void print();

    };

}

#endif
```

is this implementation of the constructor correct?

```
    template <class Data>
    lasd::Vector<Data>::Vector(){
      array = new Data[1];
      dimensione = 1;
      corrente = 0;
    }
```

tell me how you should implement a main?

Comment: Having the class in *Vector.cpp* and *Vector.h*, and than *main.cpp* which just uses it (basically an unit test suite for the class, even though you probably won't call it that) sounds like a perfectly resonable exercise project structure. Why do you think it's "not the best"?

Comment: As you should know by now, template code goes in header files, so there's no need for `vector.cpp`. Your constructor looks fine. You implement a main by writing `int main() { ... }`. You have to decide what goes inside main, presumably some code to test your vector but we can't tell you what that should be, you have to decide.

Comment: You're not asking us to help you with a specific problem, but to actually write your entire homework for you. This is not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @hyde I was told by many people on stackoverflow

Comment: @WozyWors You should always (at least when it is basics like this) know the reason, not just follow "cargo cult" rules set by others. So, why is it bad in this case?

Comment: If you professor inists on `vector.cpp` then give him one that is empty. If you professor complains then ask him what he does want.

Comment: @hyde The issue here is that the code is template code. And as is well known template code belongs in header files. No cargo cult here.

Comment: I just wanted to know how you would instantiate that class for a generic data and if there are behaviors to keep in mind for this generic data carrier

Comment: @WozyWors You cannot instantiate a class for generic data, you write a template class for generic data but you instantiate it for **specific data types**. Like this `Vector<int> v;` or this `Vector<double> v;`.

Comment: yes this was the specification I wanted. that's all it takes.guys I know that the questions about stack overflow are not so vague but unfortunately my professor of algorithms and data structures was too superficial with explanations of implementation and programming language. So I apologize again for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to have a vector.cpp file because your professor insists on it, then this is how you do it.

Write the vector.hpp containing declarations for your Vector class

Write the vector.cpp containing definitions for your Vector class

Include the vector.cpp file in the vector.hpp file like this

```
#ifndef VECTOR_HPP
#define VECTOR_HPP 

namespace lasd {

template <typename Data>
class Vector {
    ...
};

}

#include "vector.cpp"

#endif
```

That's it. Don't compile the vector.cpp file, don't include it anywhere else. Forget it ever existed. Just include the vector.hpp file where you need it.

And try and find a professor who knows what he's talking about.

Comment: therefore I should only fill in the main.cpp

Comment: In my university, teachers don’t change or choose

Comment: @WozyWors This way you can write the function definitions themselves in the `cpp` file, and so you should in order to please your professor. But in template classes, the function declarations must appear on the `hpp` file, **always**!